# How to get bearing when using Windows 10 Geolocation API

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, geolocation

I am using Windows.Devices.Geolocation in a WPF app on a Windows 10 PC and it works great. Correctly provides me with streaming latitude, longitude from the GPS satellite/location sensors. However I am using a ArcGIS API (that I cant change) that expects a bearing as one of its parameters. In Windows.Devices.Geolocation I see a heading but not a bearing. Is it hidden somewhere I cant find it, or can it perhaps be calculated from some other things Geolocation provides? Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See following : https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/

Comment: So, I don't think windows geolocalisation is as precise as that, I don't want to commit too much on that one but I guess it's based on IP and not on actual GPS, so not precise enough to get a bearing, a quick and dirty fix could be to just set a fix one.you can also calculate it as you go, as soon as you have 2 points you can calculate where the person is heading to. https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/

Comment: Thank you so much JD & Platypus for posting that link! That link helped to calculate bearing. For suggesting "calculate as you go" Platypus can you post that as an answer? I will be happy to mark it Answered.